# Custom route in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-routing

I'm working on a Zend Framework API and need to follow a particular format for URLs, so I was hoping for some help regarding how to configure the routing correctly.

http://example.com/module/controller/method/actionNameHere

The above URL would need to route to the function actionNameHereAction.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't that how ZF rolls, straight out the box? You just need to set your folder structure correctly and name your files and classes correctly?

Comment: @Leirith: Well, not exactly. He's got a that `/method/` segment in there, not sure what purpose that serves. Looks like custom routes. But, you're right, it's pretty much a standard case, right out of [the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html).

Comment: And what that part `method` stands for?

Comment: method is a static part of the URL, it will be in every request. actionNameHere should be camelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to produce the URLs needed, I ended up creating a custom Dispatcher, as it wasn't in the routing that URLs were being converted from actionNameHere to actionnamehereAction, but in the dispatcher. I extended the standard dispatcher and overrode this behaviour so that the action name in the URL remained case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of routing is that it gives you the tools for hiding exactly those pieces of information you are putting into your URL.

Apart from that, as far as I know ZF routes by default so that your URL would end up in ...

- the action with name method of
- the controller with name controller of
- the module with name module

So either your example-URL is complicating things or you are almost there.

B/c actionNameHere would be a paramter you could handle in your action with name "methodAction".

But I think you want your URL to look like:

example.com/module/controller/actionNameHere